# JQuery Mobile not refreshing button styles

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, dom-events

When I try to make an element in JQuery with code like the following:

```
$('#grid').append('<div id="gridElement'+counter+'" class="ui-block-'+rowLetter(counter)+'"></div>');
$('#gridElement'+counter).append('<div id="gridContent'+counter+'" data-inline="true"></div>');
$('#gridContent'+counter).append('<a id="button'+counter+'" href="#" data-role="button"></a>');
$('#button'+counter).html('someButtonText');
```

The elements are added properly, but the JQuery Mobile stylings are not performed. This sort of makes sense, I know that the library does a few things to the DOM as soon as it loads, but I can't figure out a way to make this happen on command. Obviously I need to instruct the JQuery Mobile library to rebuild the page, but for the life of me, I can't find anything to do this in general. I have managed to find several posts about this being a problem with select boxes and lists, but there is nothing for the page in general, grids, or buttons. Is this even possible as of now? Its still in alpha, so it may not be.

Comment: hi. did you resolve this? I have the same problem: some <a> buttons added dynamically but not picking up their styling

Answer (score 7):

Instead of refreshing the whole `div` page you can do this:

- if you are trying to refresh `data-role=collapsible` use the `collapsible()` function
- if you are trying to refresh `data-role=button` use the `button()` function

Examples:

```
$('#bank_content div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();
$('#garden_content a[data-role=button]').button();
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what worked in my case:

I hava a listview with different elements, each of it has a data-role="controlgroup" with split-buttons in it:

```
<ul id="my-list" data-role="listview" data-split-theme="a">
    <li class="list-element">
        <div class="listview-buttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="top">REMOVE</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="top">SELECT</a>
        </div>  
    </li>
    <li class="list-element">
        <div class="listview-buttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="top">REMOVE</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="top">SELECT</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

After I've added another list element (including new split buttons) dynamically with javascript, I need to refresh the list, the controlgroup and the buttons like this:

```
$('#my-list').listview('refresh'); //refresh listview first
$('.listview-buttons').children('a').buttonMarkup(); //refresh the buttons
$('.listview-buttons').controlgroup('refresh'); // then refresh the controlgroup
```

Hope that helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to that if you are trying to refresh a control group. This worked for me.

```
.buttonMarkup()
```